# is there any way to make this at seaborn scatter plots (gridplots)? python

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Hi am doing a data analisys and i need to make some scatterplots but i have to do this in a grid of 3x3 plots .for example am reading a csv file and store it as data frame.From this data frame i chose some columns to make those scatter plote.
lets supose that the name of the columns are : **1)x** **2)y** **3)z** **4)a** **5)b** **6)c**
the scatterplots that i need to make are:

```
1-4 2-4 3-4
1-5 2-5 3-5
1-6 2-6 3-6
```

and it must be seen like [image]

i used this function **sns.pairplots** it words fine but i have to do this with a **for** **loop** ,is there any way to do this please let me know

here is my code :

```
df=pd.read_csv("owid-covid-data.csv") 
//it has a lot of columns there but i want only 6.
states=['total_cases_per_million','total_deaths_per_million','mortality','gdp_per_capita','hospital_beds_per_thousand','population_density']
fig,ax=plt.subplots(3,3,figsize=(5,5))
for i ,state in enumerate(states[0:5]):
    x_var=state
    y_var=state
    sns.scatterplot(data=new_df,x=x_var,y=y_var,ax=ax[i],hue='continent')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Here is an example that shows the structure that you should follow for the grids. Here 4 times 4 and barplots but it works the same way for scatter plots and more plots:

The data I used was Spotify data of 160K song. So, the first thing is to define the size of the image AND the grid by `gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(100,100)`. The second step is to divide the grip for your plots. In my case:

```
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,0:40])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,60:100])
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,0:40])
ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,60:100])
```

After that, it's all the plots.

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[30,30])
gs  = gridspec.GridSpec(100,100)

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,0:40])
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[0:45,60:100])
ax3 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,0:40])
ax4 = fig1.add_subplot(gs[55:100,60:100])

lead_artists1 = Spotify.groupby('artists')['popularity'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(30)
ax1 = sns.barplot(x=lead_artists1.values, y=lead_artists1.index, palette="Blues", orient="h", edgecolor='white', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('Popularity All time (Count of presence in the dataset Spotify)', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('Artist', c='w', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_title('30 Most Popular Artists past 100 years', c='w', fontsize=20, weight = 'bold')


###More plots 

fig1.savefig('...../Graphs/Popularity.png')
plt.show()
```

This gave

[image]

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer.But it doesnt helped me alote,am new to this and i said if there is any way to made this with for loop .I have covid data and i need scatter plots , i used sns.pairplot(data,x_var=[],y_var=[],hue=..) where x_vars has the column names that i needed to add in grid at x axes and y_vars respectively but i have an issue it doesnt show me the diagonal plots in the 3x3 grid